# Drawing contours of polar integral function

Tags: plotting

I have a following function

```
g[s_, p_] := 
 Integrate[
  1/2*r*Log[r^2 + s^2 - 2*r*s*Cos[t - p]], {r, 0, 1/(
   2 + Cos[t])}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

I would like to draw the contour (equipotential curves) of `g[s_, p_]`. How do it do it?

Comment: `ContourPlot` is the function you want but you'll need to reverse `{r, 0, 1/( 2 + Cos[t])}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}` to `{t, 0, 2*Pi}, {r, 0, 1/(2 + Cos[t])}` and use `NIntegrate` rather than `Integrate`.

Comment: @JimB Do you mean like this `g[s_, p_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  1/2*r*Log[r^2 + s^2 - 2*r*s*Cos[t - p]], {r, 0, 1/(
   2 + Cos[t])}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
ContourPlot[g[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[y/x]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`

Comment: No.  You still need to reverse the order of the integration variables and `Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[y/x]` isn't in your question.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Clear[g];
g[s_, p_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  1/2*r*Log[r^2 + s^2 - 2*r*s*Cos[t - p]], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, {r, 0, 
   1/(2 + Cos[t])}]
```

- View the `Plot3D` of  `z=g[s,p]` in cylinder coordinate by `DisplayFunction ->  ReplaceAll[{s_Real, p_Real, z_Real} :> {s*Cos@p, s*Sin@p, z}]`

```
Plot3D[g[s, p], {s, 0, 3}, {p, 0, 2 π}, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{s_Real, p_Real, z_Real} :> {s*Cos@p, s*Sin@p, z}], 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 20, PlotRange -> All, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", ViewPoint -> Top, PlotPoints -> 60,
  MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image]

- View the `g[s,p]` in polar coordinate in `ContourPlot` by `DisplayFunction ->  ReplaceAll[{s_Real, p_Real} :> {s*Cos@p, s*Sin@p}]`

```
ContourPlot[g[s, p], {s, 0, 3}, {p, 0, 2 π}, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{s_Real, p_Real} :> {s*Cos@p, s*Sin@p}], 
 PlotRange -> All, BoundaryStyle -> None, Contours -> 20, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
g[s_, p_] := NIntegrate[1/2*r*Log[r^2 + s^2 - 2*r*s*Cos[t - p]], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, {r, 0, 1/(2 + Cos[t])}]
AbsoluteTiming[ContourPlot[g[s, p], {s, -2, 2}, {p, -2, 2}]]
```

[image: Contour plot and execution time]

Comment: This should be in polar coordinates not in cartesian ones.

Comment: I think you can take it from here.

Answer (score 4):

Just another way using`MeshFunctions`.

As with other answers using `NIntegrate` and changing order integration.

This is not efficient but does work. I have not illustrated size of contours.

```
g[s_,p_]:= NIntegrate[1/2 * r * Log[r^2 + s^2 - 2 * r * s * Cos[t-p]], {t, 0, 2 * Pi}, {r, 0, 1/ (2 + Cos[t])}]


Quiet@ParametricPlot[ {r Cos[t], r Sin[t]},{r, 0.1, 3}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},MeshFunctions->(g[#3, #4]&), Mesh->5]
```

[image]

Comment: Sin[t]) should be Sin[t]}

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected error.